# Dynamic route to fetch user details from my api

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

So i have a route on my back-end that returns me a Json object with user details, it has a parameter "cn" that you must pass like "localhost/user/cn".
In my front-end i already have a route that returns me a json object with the user list and displays it on a table.
Now i want to click each user and redirect to a new page that displays the user details.
I checked this website "https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/recipes/" but i could't reproduce since i am pretty beginner in this.
My Project Structure is:

```
|-- /frontend   
   |-- /src
      |-- /Components
        |-- /users
           |-- index.js
           |-- users.jsx
        |-- /userDetails
           |-- index.js
           |-- userdetails.jsx
      |-- /pages
        |-- users.js
        |-- userdetails.jsx
|-- gatsby-config.js
|-- gatsby-node.js
|-- gatsby-ssr.js
|-- gatsby-browser.js
```

In my component folder i have a "users.jsx" that has a function which returns a table mapping the json object.
In my pages folder i have a "users.js" that displays me the list of users.
This works fine.
Now i can't come up with the code to do the details for each user.

```
users.jsx

export default function User ({ data })  {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (

    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <Table className={classes.table} size="small">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="left">User</TableCell>
             <Link to='/details'></Link>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            {data.map(user => (
            <TableRow  key={user.User}>
              <TableCell align="left">{user} </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
users.js

import React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import User from "../components/users"
import MainComponentWrapper from "../components/mainComponentWrapper"


const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <MainComponentWrapper url="http://localhost:5000/user">
      <User  />
    </MainComponentWrapper>
  </Layout>
)
export default IndexPage
```

I'am fetching the data with a wapper that has a function to check for the token and fetches the data with a url as a parameter,i pass this url up here in the MainComponentWrapper.

If i click a user it should use the cn as a parameter and get the user details with my route that i have in the back-end:

```
@app.route('/user/<cn>', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def user_details(cn):


        user_details = ldap.get_object_details(cn, query_filter="cn=%s")

        if user_details is None:
            response = jsonify(message='User Not Found')
            return response, 404
        return jsonify(user_details)
```

Any code example how i would do this?
I saw in gatsby website that i need to create a gatsby-node.js file to use the createpages, but i don't know if this applies to my case.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is client-only routes. This basically allows you to create a 'regular' React page that can also accept arguments through the url like so:

```
/* gatsby-node.js */

// This is executed at build time. For each page you have in your pages folder,
// it will call this method.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    // This will evaluate to true if the page being created is the 'user.js'
    // page.
    if (page.path.match("/user/")) {
        // matchPath will tell the new page to match any path that starts with
        // '/user/', and to pass the remainder of the url to the page element
        // as a prop called 'cn'.
        createPage({...page, matchPath: "/user/:cn"});
    }

};
```

I'm assuming a scenario where you have a page in your pages folder called 'user.js' that you want to render when someone clicks a user from your list. This 'user.js' page should show the details of the user you clicked. You can set the link in the list to 'user/whatever-the-value-of-cn-is-for-this-user'.

The 'onCreatePage' hook is called for every page you have in your pages folder. So your 'user.js' file will also pass through here. When it comes by, you use the createPage action to create the page, with an extra argument passed in: matchPath, which will in this case match any path that starts with 'user'. The 'cn' part of the url will be passed as a prop to the page, so from there you can call the API endpoint with the cn of the user, and render the user details.

Hope this helps!